# Spark 2.1.0 reverse proxy does not work properly

Tags: apache-spark, proxy

I'm trying to proxy individual spark applications. That means I need to get a single UI per spark application. To achieve that, I use the spark reverse proxy feature. So, if I have my spark master UI running at http://localhost:8080, when I click on one application name from this spark UI, I'm redirected to http://localhost:8080/proxy/{application-id}/jobs/ where application-id is the application id of the spark application I'm trying to access. Everything looks good, I get the spark job UI for this particular application and some other tabs displayed. But when I click on another tab, for instance "Environment" I'm redirected to http://localhost:8080/environment instead of http://localhost/proxy/{application-id}/environment/

This is the single line I add in my spark-defaults.conf file

```
spark.ui.reverseProxy=true
```

I use spark 2.1.0 in standalone mode and deploy some sample applications to reproduce the issue. Any clue? How can I make this proxy working without this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, from the master I can go the workers, but the back links are wrong and will not work.
The workers are configured with the `spark.ui.reverseProxy` option and in the startup logs I can see "WorkerWebUI is available at" and the proxied URL, but still the links generated by the worker are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

Make sure that you correctly supply `spark.ui.reverseProxy` and `spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl` properties to all masters, workers and **drivers**.

In my case I used `spark-submit` (cluster mode) from remote machine and forgot to update local `spark-defaults.conf` on the machine I was submitting from.